# When listening for keypress in Flash Lite should I be listening for Key.Down or the numeric code for this key?

Tags: adobe, mobile-phones, keylistener, flashlite, device-emulation

The adobe documentation says that when listening for a keypress event from a phone you should listen for **Key.Down**, however when I trace the Key.getCode() of keypresses I see a number not the string "**Key.Down**". I am tesing this locally in device central and do not have a phone to test this with at present. Here is my code -

```
keyListener = new Object();
keyListener.onKeyDown = function() {
    switch (Key.getCode()) {
    trace(Key.getCode()) // outputs 40
        case (Key.DOWN) : // according to the docs
          pressDown();
        break;
    }
}
```

My question is - is this simply because Im testing in device central and when I run it on the phone I will need to be listening for Key.Down? or is the documentation wrong? Also is the numeric code (40) consistent across all devices? What gives adobe?

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Key.Down` is equal to 40 so it will recognize it as the same. So you can use whichever one you prefer, however, I would recommend using `Key.Down` because it will be easily recognizeable for those who dont have Key Codes memorized (most of us).

These are the [Key Code Values for Javascript](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx). However, I think they are pretty much universal